# Pandas Not importing csv file correctly

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys I've looked around a lot with importing csv files using pandas however even though my file path is correct I get thrown tons of errors

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Liam\PycharmProjects\assignment1\pipeline-incidents-comprehensive-data.csv")

print(df)
```

[all errors as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viqCe.jpg)

I am very new to python (1 week) so i do realize this is a very simple problem so any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, are you sure that's the code you're running? The error implies you wrote `r"\C:\Users...` (with the \ at the very beginning).

Comment: Please pay attention to correctly copy your code! The error says that your source actually is `df = pd.read_csv(r"\C:\Users\...` with an initial (and erroneous `\ `)